# How to deploy a new version after a failed one on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy an app to elastic beanstalk via `Dockerrun.aws.json` in the browser.
I click on `Create Application`, choose `local file` and input `version label` as `v0.0.0`

Deplyment doesn't work because there is an error in my file, so I fix that and want to upload a new version.

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html#deployments-newversion I go to the navigation pane, choose **Environments**, choose my environment, click on `Upload and deploy` and select my changed local file. The suggested new version label is `v0.0.0-1`. I accept that and click on **deploy**.
My second deployment then fails, apparenty because of versioning because under `Health` it says
`Incorrect application version "v0.0.0-1" (deployment 2). Expected version "v0.0.0" (deployment 1).`

I would like to understand why I cannot deploy the way I'm trying to and how to do it right.

## Things I've tried:

### Terminate the environment and create a new one

Works but takes a lot of time.

### Deploying under the same version via `Upload and Deploy`

(ensuring same conditions by terminating current environment, creating new one, failing first deployment)
As the old version is expected, I try to enter the old version label `v0.0.0` for the second deployment.
I click on `Upload and deploy` but the form doesn't allow for that and says `An application version with that label already exists.`

[image]

### Deploying under the same version via `Application versions`

Marcin suggested `Application versions`. There I can see the original version which failed:

[image]

now I can upload a new file

- under a new version. [image] which on **deploy** fails as before with `Incorrect application version "v0.0.0-1" (deployment 2). Expected version "v0.0.0" (deployment 1).` [image]
- under the same version, replacing the original entry. [image] (For this I select the existing entry, choose action **delete** after which the entry persists then I select upload and now I can assign the old version)
  But when I deploy that it fails with `Incorrect application version "v0.0.0" (deployment 2). Expected version "v0.0.0" (deployment 1).` [image]

Answer (score 3):

You should deploy old versions from `Application Version` page.

The window you have screenshot-ed in the question, is to upload a **new version**, not re-deploy the old one. Thus you get the error message, that you want to label a new version of your application as an old version.

However, if you want to upload old version yourself again, you have to assign a new, non-existing label for it.

As a side note for a future, you can minimize the impact of failed deployments on your current environment by using either `immutable` or `blue/green` strategies.

Comment: But how can I deploy a new version then?

Comment: @peer You use the upload form, from your screenshot.

Comment: But that doesn't work, I get: `Incorrect application version "v0.0.1" (deployment 2). Expected version "v0.0.0" (deployment 1).`

Comment: @peer [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html#deployments-newversion) are the AWS  instructions on uploading new version, and redeploying old.

Comment: That's how I did it in the first place... I've restructured my question and integrated your input so far. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @peer could you provide screenshot of your `Application Versions`. Also could you indicate which one failed, and which one you want to deploy?

Comment: I've added some screenshots

Comment: @peer It seems to be something more difficult. May need to login to the instances and inspect their log files to see what's happening. Can also try to reboot the instance, or even terminate it so that ASG replaces it with fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I deployed a multi docker container app (`"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2`) but did not select `Multi-container` as a Platform branch.